# How to mark options as selected

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-admin

How can i set selected atribute to options inside of `<SelectArrayInput>` component? I have not realized how to set selected atribute yet.

I have already tried to put there a attribute selected, but it doesnt seem to work.

```
const tec = [
    { name: "Apple", id: 1, selected: true},
    { name: "Facebook", id: 2 },
    { name: "Netflix", id: 3 },
    { name: "Tesla", id: 4 },
    ];

const ReferrenceSelectBox = ({ source, record = {} }) => <SelectArrayInput choices={ tec } />;

ReferrenceSelectBox.propTypes = {
    label: PropTypes.string,
    record: PropTypes.object,
    source: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

export default ReferrenceSelectBox;
```

I expect the output of `<SelectArrayInput>` with already selected options.

Comment: is Material-Ui tag relevant? From the code snippet it doesn't look like you are using it

Comment: That is right, I removed the tag

Comment: Going through the [docs](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/docs/Inputs.md#selectarrayinput) of `react-admin` it looks like they are using Material-UI `Select` behind the scenes. So, tag may be relevant :-) also can you please add the version of `react-admin` you are using?

Comment: I am using 2.6.1

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to get a code sandbox working with `react-admin`, but from the [documentation](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/docs/Inputs.md#selectarrayinput) it looks like it is using the `Select` from Material-ui as the base.

In Material-UI you can pass the values to be selected as a prop: `value` which takes an array of the `ids` that you want.

So, in your case, instead of having `selected` attribute, you can create another array which captures the `selectedIds` and pass it as `value` prop and it should work.

```
const tec = [
    { name: "Apple", id: 1},
    { name: "Facebook", id: 2 },
    { name: "Netflix", id: 3 },
    { name: "Tesla", id: 4 },
    ];
const selectedTec = [1];
const ReferrenceSelectBox = ({ source, record = {} }) => <SelectArrayInput value={ selectedTec } choices={ tec } />;

ReferrenceSelectBox.propTypes = {
    label: PropTypes.string,
    record: PropTypes.object,
    source: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

export default ReferrenceSelectBox;
```

Comment: Maybe this should be solution, but at this moment It does not work, I also tried to put inside the `selectedTec` the whole `{ name: "Apple", id: 1}` , but still nothing

Comment: Any ideas how to do this? @dubes

Comment: I think if I can reproduce it, I can have some better ideas. If possible, can you please try to create a codesandbox.io with your react, react-admin and other dependencies?

Comment: try using `source` as the prop name instead of value. Also I see a working example in https://codesandbox.io/s/wn5k6kqo2k file name: PostEdit.js, but I have not used react-admin so I can't say what is going on, but perhaps it makes sense to you